# How to check which exception is contained in a Failure[T]?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm wondering about the best way to check the content of a failed `Try` using ScalaTest. What I'm doing at the moment looks like this:

```
"Subject" should "throw proper exceptions.." in {
  a[IllegalArgumentException] should be thrownBy {
    val tryValue = // some method call..
    if (tryValue.isFailure) throw tryValue.failed.get
  }
}
```

As you can see, I just unwrap the exception and throw it manually. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: first off, before getting into fancier stuff - you can replace `if (tryValue.isFailure) throw tryValue.failed.get` with `tryValue.get`.

Comment: @TzachZohar I don't think it's semantically the same thing. If the `tryValue` is not a `Failure` but a `Success`, then another exception is thrown  (due to the `get` call) which makes the potential test results more complex (yes, the test will fail anyway, but still). Or am I wrong?

Comment: If tryValue is not a Failure but a Success - no exception will be thrown, and test will fail elegantly saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but no exception was thrown`, which is exactly the same as what you'd get with your code.

Comment: You are right. For some reason I've read `failed.get` instead of just `get`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with something that doesn't really *throw* the exception, given that a `Failure` result is just another result that can be matched:

```
"Subject" should "throw proper exceptions.." in {
  val tryValue = // some method call...
  tryValue shouldBe a[Failure[_]]
  tryValue.failed.get shouldBe an[IllegalArgumentException]
}
```

The above separates the assertions: you'll see different test failures for the case where no failure happened and the case where the wrong failure happened.

Comment: This is what I also had in mind, but I wasn't sure if circumventing the exception mechanism of the test framework (here: `thrownBy`) is seen as good practice. However, I think it looks good, so thanks.

Comment: This can simply be `tryValue shouldBe a[Failure[IllegalArgumentException]]`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful

```
   Try(1 / 0) match {
          case Success(success) =>
          case Failure(error)   => println(error.getClass.getName)

        }
```

**Result:** `java.lang.ArithmeticException`